# refresh html content with each new GET request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, get

I have been *practicing* my Vanilla Js/jQuery skills today by throwing together a newsfeed app using the [news-api](https://newsapi.org/).

I have included a link to a jsfiddle of my code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/sagbmb8h/). However, I have removed my `API` key.

On first load of the page, when the user clicks on an image for a media outlet, e.g. 'techcrunch', using an `addEventListener`, I pass the image's `id attribute` to the `API` end point `'https://newsapi.org/v1/articles'` and run a `GET` request which then proceeds to create `div` elements with the news articles content.

However, after clicking 1 image, I cannot get the content to reload unless I reload the whole page manually or with `location.reload()`.

On clicking another image the new `GET` request *is* running and returning results, as I am console logging the results.

I am looking for some general guidance on how to get the page content to reload with each new `GET` request.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks for your time.

**Api convention:**

e.g `https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=techcrunch&apiKey=APIKEYHERE`

**EventListener:**

```
sourceIMG.addEventListener('click', function() {
    $.get('https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=' + this.id + '&sortBy=latest&apiKey=APIKEYHERE', function(data, status) {
        console.log(data);
        latestArticles = data.articles;
        for (i = 0; i < latestArticles.length; i++) {
            //New Article
            var newArticle = document.createElement("DIV");
            newArticle.id = "article";
            newArticle.className += "article";
            //Title
            //Create an h1 Element
            var header = document.createElement("H1");
            //Create the text entry for the H1
            var title = document.createTextNode(latestArticles[i].title);
            //Append the text to the h1 Element
            header.appendChild(title);
            //Append the h1 element to the Div 'article'
            newArticle.appendChild(header);
            //Author
            var para = document.createElement("P");
            var author = document.createTextNode(latestArticles[i].author);
            para.appendChild(author);
            newArticle.appendChild(para);
            //Description
            var description = document.createElement("H4");
            var desc = document.createTextNode(latestArticles[i].description);
            description.appendChild(desc);
            newArticle.appendChild(description);
            //Image
            var image = document.createElement("IMG");
            image.src = latestArticles[i].urlToImage;
            image.className += "articleImg";
            newArticle.appendChild(image);
            //Url link
            //Create a href element
            var a = document.createElement('a');
            var link = document.createElement('p');
            var innerLink = document.createTextNode('Read the full story ');
            link.appendChild(innerLink);
            a.setAttribute("href", latestArticles[i].url);
            a.innerHTML = "here.";
            link.appendChild(a);
            newArticle.appendChild(link);
            //Append the Div 'article' to the outer div 'articles'
            document.getElementById("articles").appendChild(newArticle);
        }
    });
}, false);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your fiddle using an api key. It is working for me in that content new content is appended to the previous content in the #articles div. If I'm understanding your question, when a news service image is clicked you would like for only that news service's articles to show. To do that you would need to clear the contents of #articles before appending new content.

To do that with plain js you could use the following above your for loop:

```
   // Removing all children from an element
   var articlesDiv = document.getElementById("articles");
   while (articlesDiv.firstChild) {
     articlesDiv.removeChild(articlesDiv.firstChild);
   }

   for (i = 0; i < latestArticles.length; i++) {...
```

Full disclosure, I added the variable name 'articlesDiv' but otherwise the above snippet came from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/removeChild

Comment: This worked once I added it into the GET request, before the assignation of data = latestArticles. Thanks again!